# Powershell remove lines containing the incorrect number of words

Tags: powershell, count

Can this be done in easily or at all in powershell?
How would one remove all lines from "test.txt" that do not contain exactly 24 words

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [Tour] and (re-)read the help topic [Ask] to set your expectations on SO.  ... and yes this can easily be done in Powershell.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not too hard in PowerShell.

Something like below should do it:

```
# read the file and use Where-Object to capture only those lines that have 24 words exactly.
# the regex -split uses '\W+', meaning to split each line on (at least one) Non-Word character.
$result = Get-Content -Path 'D:\test.txt' | Where-Object { ($_ -split '\W+').Count -eq 24 }

# output on screen
$result

# write output to new file
$result | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\test24.txt' -Force
```